# How do you specify the availability zone while creating a DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am not able to figure out how to specify the availability zone while creating a DynamoDB table using the AWS SDK for Java. It creates a table in the US East region by default.

Appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AWS SDK for Java 1.3.8, it is still not implemented.
I believe it will be implemented in the next SDK update.

In the meanwhile as a WORKAROUND you can set it manually after the construction of the `AmazonDynamoDBClient` object with the function `setEndpoint`.

For example for EU:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient dbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(creds);
dbClient.setEndpoint("dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/");
```